# What does a lowercase "a" mean for guitar music?

Tags: guitar, notation, fingering

What does a lowercase letter "a" next to the notehead mean for guitar music?

[image: Music for guitar in both staff notation and tablature. In the staff notation there are small letter a's and m's next to some noteheads.]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm curious that you didn't ask about the "m"s also. They are there for the same reason. Both are indications of which right hand finger the composer or editor suggests you use to play the note.

- *p* is short for *pulgar*, Spanish for "thumb"
- *i* is short for *indice* - "index finger"
- *m* is short for *medio* - "middle finger"
- *a* is short for *anular* - "ring finger"

Comment: Ah, thanks! Well, I did suspect at first that _m_ might mean "middle" finger but then I didn't know what _a_ could mean—I didn't know there was another word for the ring finger—so I dismissed that suspicion. Then I asked in particular about the _a_ because it happens to be the note I'm having trouble with—I didn't need help with the _m_ ones, though I was curious about that too.

Comment: Interesting that there's no initial for the pinky. A lot of us use that almost as much as the other digits. But in classical guitar playing it appears to be taboo. Wonder why? +1.

Comment: @Tim it’s not taboo as such, but with a good, traditional, right hand position its shortness tends to limit its use. When learning and potentially needing RH finger suggestions you’re unlikely to use the little finger for classical guitar so I guess the system never ended up incorporating it. It is of course used, but often for more special-effecty things in classical guitar which you don’t see too often and don’t come with the usual finger notation.

Comment: As far as I know, the names origin from Spanish, although they are indeed almost identical in Italian. In various scores, pinky notation sometimes occurs, but I saw various letters assigned to this. And although some classical guitarists use pinky, it seems not to be a part of the regular curriculum. Why? – that would be a good separate question @Tim